# Options to install Ethereum nodes in a corporate environment

Tags: installation

The main issue to install an Ethereum node in a corporate environment is the possibility to receive connection from unknown nodes. The security department is always concerned in open new doors to attacks since it is a public net.

Is it possible to configure an Ethereum node in a way that it can create connection with external nodes but it cannot accept any connection from unknown nodes? 
What are the consequences of this architecture? Would it be possible to send new transactions with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Corporate environments aren't new to putting things in the DMZ. Public APIs are always in the DMZ. You have a few options here:

1. Run a node outside any firewalls, likely on AWS, completely separate from your current network. Then, run a node within your firewall, and open up your firewall *only* to the node you put outside your network. This way you get the connectivity of a public node, but the security of your firewall.
2. Run a node outside any firewalls completely separate from your current network. Then, just run any queries you need to against the public JSON-rpc of this node. This approach may be slightly slower than option 1 since you.